# C3 timeseries chart giving error Invalid value for <path> attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to generate a timeseries chart with c3.js, everything works fine except when I try to add date on x.axis it suddenly gives error invalid value. I do not understand why that is I am following the exact style of c3 docs. [jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/yrzxj3x2/1/)

code:

```
 var chart = c3.generate({
         bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      x: 'x',
        columns: [
        ["x", "2016-01-04", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-07", "2016-01-08", "2016-01-09", "2016-01-10", "2016-01-11", "2016-01-12", "2016-01-13", "2016-01-14", "2016-01-15", "2016-01-16", "2016-01-17", "2016-01-18", "2016-01-19", "2016-01-20", "2016-01-21", "2016-01-22", "2016-01-23", "2016-01-24", "2016-01-25", "2016-01-26", "2016-01-27", "2016-01-28", "2016-01-29", "2016-01-30", "2016-01-31", "2016-02-01", "2016-02-02", "2016-02-03"],
         ["Democrates", 49.85, 49.89, 49.82, 49.51, 49.42, 49.33, 49.24, 49.64, 49.57, 49.57, 49.01, 48.67, 48.7, 48.7, 48.7, 48.63, 48.63, 48.63, 48.63, 48.63, 48.61, 48.61, 48.68, 48.76, 48.84, 48.73, 48.76, 48.79, 48.81, 49.68, 49.63],
         ["Republicans", "50.15", "50.11", "50.18", "50.49", "50.58", "50.67", "50.76", "50.36", "50.43", "50.43", "50.99", "51.33", "51.30", "51.30", "51.30", "51.37", "51.37", "51.37", "51.37", "51.37", "51.39", "51.39", "51.32", "51.24", "51.16", "51.27", "51.24", "51.21", "51.19", "50.32", "50.37"]
        ],
         colors: {
            Democrates: '#4575b4',
            Republicans: '#d73027'
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: You probably want both series to be numbers. The second one is strings at the moment, which is likely causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yrzxj3x2/3/

You have to tell the x axis to be of type 'timeseries' and defining the format doesn't hurt. This is the bit that enabled timeseries on your chart:

```
axis: {
     x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
              format: '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
     }
 }
```

See reference on here: http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html